# How do I transfer my whatsapp messages from old phone to new phone?

Tags: samsung, whatsapp-messenger, restore

I've been using Samsung Tab and the USB cable is not usable. I've been seeing answers like backing up my messages to my SD card from my old phone and insert it to my new phone, but the problem is my new phone ( Samsung Alpha ) doesn't have the SD card slot. So is there any other way to transfer my Whatsapp messages without the use of USB cable and SD card?

Comment: Transfer the `msgstore.db.crypt` via bluetooth or upload it to cloud(drive, dropbox etc) from your old phone  and download it to new phone..Install whastapp in you new phone and try to restore this backup..

Comment: If one phone supports hotspot capabilities and both have wifi then you can use an app like [Xender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=cn.xender&hl=en) to transfer files (the one suggested by @Lucky, or in the answer) locally.

Answer (score 1):

You should upload the `Whatsapp` folder (to google drive, etc.) on your old device and download it again on your new device. Then copy the directory to `/sdcard`.

Hope I helped you!

Answer (score 0):

You can upload Your messages and media to GOOGLE DRIVE via the backup option in the Whatsapp application. You can download all those messages once logged in to google and whatsapp in your new phone.